# Pass objects to web api controller

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-web-api

Using jQuery and .net web api I haven't an issue with passing a single object to a controller. What I'm struggling with is passing more than a single object to the controller. I've already seen some samples of similar but they only talk about single object passing which I haven't an issue with. Here is the jQuery code:

```
var data = settings.itemArray;
if (data.length == 0) return;

$.post(sApi.data.Update, JSON.stringify({'data':data}),
function (results) {
    if (results > 0) { }
});
```

settings.itemArray consists of an array of 4 objects.

My controller is like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody]List<M.DataVal> data)
    {
        var d = data.Count();
    }
```

The Dataval in code behind is defined like this

```
public class DataVal
{
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Area { get; set; }
}
```

This works just fine if I change it from a list to a single object but not multiple. Doing JSON.stringify doesn't make a difference and neither does setting the type of request method on the controller. I've also made sure that it going with header of Content-Type: application/json. I can see the data in the Form Data post in chromes developer tools so the data is going through and it is in the form of:

```
{"data":[{"AgencyId":80,"Year":2011,"Value":6546,"Area":1},{"AgencyId":80,"Year":2011,"Value":654654,"Area":2},{"AgencyId":80,"Year":2011,"Value":6456,"Area":3}]}:
```

Anyone know of a way to get multiple object passed to a controller or see what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you able to put your answer in the "Your Answer" section below, just to be consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Seems you need to send anonymous type to the web api when you want to send multiple objects as an array. Found the answer over at http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/post-an-array-of-objects-to-webapi-using-jquery/.

So, the jQuery would look like this:

```
$.post(sApi.data.Update, { '': data },
function (results) {
if (results > 0) { }
});
```

Doing this change results in all my objects being passed and being available. Hope this helps someone.